# Get First Day Of Week From Week Number

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle, is there a straightforward way to get the first day of the week given a week number?

For example, today's date is 12/4/2012.  If I run:
select to_char(sysdate,'WW') from dual;
It returns 49 for the week number.

What I would like to do is somehow return 12/2/2012 for the first day...given week 49 (assuming Sunday as first day of the week).

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
select next_day(max(d), 'sun') requested_sun
  from (select to_date('01-01-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + (rownum-1) d from dual connect by level <= 366)
 where to_char(d, 'ww') = 49-1;
```

just set your year `to_date('01-01-2012'` and week number-1 `49-1` as applicable.

the sunday in the 49th week of 2008?

```
SQL> select next_day(max(d), 'sun') requested_sun
  2    from (select to_date('01-01-2008', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + (rownum-1) d from dual connect by level <= 366)
  3   where to_char(d, 'ww') = 49-1;

REQUESTED
---------
07-DEC-08
```

and 2012

```
SQL> select next_day(max(d), 'sun') requested_sun
  2    from (select to_date('01-01-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + (rownum-1) d from dual connect by level <= 366)
  3   where to_char(d, 'ww') = 49-1;

REQUESTED
---------
02-DEC-12
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
select 
  next_day(trunc(to_date(in_year,'yyyy'),'yyyy') -1,'Mon') + (7 * (in_week - 1)) 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the date, not just the week number, you can try this:

- Get the day number of the week of your date with: `to_char(theDate, 'D')`
- substract that number from your date plus 1, and you'll get the Sunday of that week.
- Add 7 and you'll get the date of end of the week(Saturday).

Like this:

```
SELECT theDate - to_char(theDate, 'D') + 1 as BeginOfWeek, 
       theDate,
       theDate - to_char(theDate, 'D') + 7 as EndOfWeek
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Awesome, simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on questions yet, so I'll add another one. But this is based on @Dazzals answer.
His solution doesn't work for week one and for ISO-weeks. Also it doesn't work, if the first day of the week is not sunday, which can be controlled by NLS_SETTINGS.

This one does:

```
SELECT MIN(D)
FROM (SELECT TO_DATE('01-01-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy') + (ROWNUM-10) D, ROWNUM R 
        FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 376)
WHERE TO_CHAR(D,'IYYYIW') = '201301'
```

Because we are spanning more than one year, we need to check the year too.

Answer (score 0):

Using the trunc function @Justin used, I think this is what you want:

```
select trunc(to_date('2012-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (49 - 1) * 7, 'WW') from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response JDunkerley.  However, it looks like this doesn't always work.  For example, if I plug in the year 2008 to your script it looks like: select trunc(to_date('2008-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + (49 - 1) * 7, 'WW') from dual;  And this will return 12/2/2008, which is a Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
function getFirstDayOfWeek(y in binary_integer, w in binary_integer) return date
is
td date;
begin
    td:=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(y)||'0101', 'YYYYMMDD');
    for c in 0..52
    loop
        if TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(td, 'IW'))=w then
            return TRUNC(td, 'IW');
        end if;
        td:=td+7;
    end loop;
    return null;
end;
```