# day of the week in the week numbering

Tags: sql, oracle, date

in oracle there is a possibility to change starting day of the week.
In US first day is SUN, and in EU - MON

This change works by changing nls_territory

However if I consider day of the week and week numbering at once, I have following situation:

```
day week_number
  7          9   <- here it should be still week 8
  1          9
  2          9
  3          9
  4          9
  5          9
  6          9
  7         10  <- here it should still be week 9
```

Do you have any idea which nls should could affect this start_day of the week?

Similar post
[Get First Day Of Week From Week Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706558/get-first-day-of-week-from-week-number)

Comment: The question that had answer close to what i was looking for was checked. However the other questions didn't result in the answer/s i would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has two date formats which give us the Week Number.

'WW' starts from the first of January and increments every seven days.  As 01-JAN-2013 was a Tuesday that means the Week Number increments on a Tuesday.  I guess this is the version you're using at the moment.

But there is also the 'IW' format, which is the ISO standard.  In this version, the week number starts from the Monday of the week where the first of January falls.  This has the peculiar side-effect of making 31-DEC-2012 the first date of Week 1 on 2013, but it does mean the week number always increments on day 1 of the week.

[Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question and I see no connection between day# and week# in your example, sorry... Maybe this will help you to get ISO week. This builds annual week table. You may add 'WW' format to the query and compare dates, weeks in diff. NLS settings:

```
   -- ISO_WK# --
   SELECT mydate
    , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') wk_starts
    , TRUNC(mydate, 'w') + 7 - 1/86400 wk_ends
    , TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (mydate, 'IW')) ISO_wk#  
   FROM
   (
    SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-1 + LEVEL AS mydate
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
      (
        SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')-TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'YEAR') "Num of Days"   
         FROM dual
      )
   )
  /
```