# Week, Month, Year number to beginning of week Date

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:

- Month Number : 03
- Week Number: 10
- Year : 2018

I want this to convert to 3/05/2018 but am unsure how to do this in Tableau/Oracle SQL. What would be the logic to convert these 3 separate numbers into the beginning of a week? The week would start on Monday.

Thanks

Comment: You should use [Date functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Date_Functions.html#DALc02a_2726006080_11805).

Comment: When you have the week number, why do you need the month number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get First Day Of Week From Week Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706558/get-first-day-of-week-from-week-number)

Comment: 03/06/2018 is a Tuesday, not a Monday?

Comment: @AlexPoole, just updated, my mistake

Comment: 3/5/18: Do you mean March 5th or May 3rd? I assume you mean March 5th but want to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**The following query should give you the desired result -**

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(START_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS START_DATE
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (TRUNC(TO_DATE('2018','YYYY'),'DAY') + 1) + ((LEVEL - 1) * 7) AS START_DATE,
        (TRUNC(TO_DATE('2018','YYYY'),'DAY') + 1) + ((LEVEL - 1) * 7) + 6 AS END_DATE, LEVEL AS WEEK
    FROM 
        DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (((TO_DATE('2018','YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR) + INTERVAL '-1' DAY) - (TO_DATE('2018','YYYY')))/7
)
WHERE
    WEEK = 10
;
```

> The year 2018 and week number 10 are hardcoded here to get the desired
>   result in this case.

**Result:-**

### START_DATE

03/05/2018

Answer (score 0):

I think Month Number is not necessary, you can try below code,

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE((&week_no*7)||' &yyyy', 'DDD YYYY')-7, 2) date_
  FROM dual;

week_no = 10
yyyy = 2018

DATE_   
---------
05-MAR-18
```