# JOOQ : Given a year and the week number, Need the start date of the week

Tags: jooq

Given a year and the week number, How to get the start date of that particular week using JOOQ.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: oracle 12c @LukasEder

Answer (score 0):

The particular vendor specific functions needed for this query aren't currently supported by jOOQ 3.16, but you can easily do something like this: [Get First Day Of Week From Week Number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13706558/521799)

And use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to access the native SQL functions